# Dont get data in JList

Tags: java, mysql, import, jlist

```
package gui;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import data.Astromon;
import data.AstromonException;
import data.Attribute;
import data.Star;
import db.DBAccess;

public class StartView extends JFrame
{

    JPanel ListPanel = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel InfoPanel = new JPanel(); 


    //// JListPanel Components
    DefaultListModel<Astromon> dlmAstro = new DefaultListModel<>();
    JList<Astromon> aList = new JList<>(); 

    JComboBox<Star> cbStars = new JComboBox<>(Star.values());
    JComboBox<Attribute> cbAttribute = new JComboBox<>(Attribute.values());
    JButton btConfirm = new JButton(); 

    JPanel filter = new JPanel(); 
    JScrollPane astroList = new JScrollPane();
    //// JInfoPanel Components
    JPanel StatTable = new JPanel(); 

    JLabel lbHP = new JLabel("HP");
    JLabel lbATK = new JLabel("ATK");
    JLabel lbDEF = new JLabel("DEF");
    JLabel lbREC = new JLabel("REC");
    JLabel lbCR = new JLabel("Crit Rate");
    JLabel lbCD = new JLabel("Crit Damage");
    JLabel lbRES = new JLabel("RES");

    JLabel lbHPStat = new JLabel("HP-Stat");
    JLabel lbATKStat = new JLabel("ATK-Stat");
    JLabel lbDEFStat = new JLabel("DEF-Stat");
    JLabel lbRECStat = new JLabel("REC-Stat");
    JLabel lbCRStat = new JLabel("Crit Rate-Stat");
    JLabel lbCDStat = new JLabel("Crit Damage-Stat");
    JLabel lbRESStat = new JLabel("RES-Stat");

    JPanel GeneralInfo = new JPanel(); 
    JLabel lbIcon = new JLabel("Icon");
    JLabel lbAttribute = new JLabel("Attribut");
    JLabel lbRole = new JLabel("Role");
    JLabel lbStar = new JLabel("Nat*");

    JPanel PanelGems = new JPanel(); 
    JButton btGem1 = new JButton("Gem1"); 
    JButton btGem2 = new JButton("Gem2"); 
    JButton btGem3 = new JButton("Gem3"); 



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new StartView();
    }

    public StartView()
    {
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 500);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        initListPanel(); 
        initInfoPanel();
        fillListModel("All"); 

        ButtonHandler();    
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initListPanel()
    {
        this.add(ListPanel);
        ListPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        filter.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        filter.add(cbStars);
        filter.add(cbAttribute);
        aList.setModel(dlmAstro);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(aList);
        astroList.add(scrollPane);




        ListPanel.add(filter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ListPanel.add(astroList, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void initInfoPanel()
    {
        // InfoPanel
        InfoPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        StatTable.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,3));
        StatTable.add(lbHP);
        StatTable.add(lbHPStat);
        StatTable.add(lbATK);
        StatTable.add(lbATKStat);
        StatTable.add(lbDEF);
        StatTable.add(lbDEFStat);
        StatTable.add(lbREC);
        StatTable.add(lbRECStat);
        StatTable.add(lbCR);
        StatTable.add(lbCRStat);
        StatTable.add(lbCD);
        StatTable.add(lbCDStat);
        StatTable.add(lbRES);
        StatTable.add(lbRESStat);

        // GeneralInfoPanel
        GeneralInfo.add(lbIcon);
        GeneralInfo.add(lbAttribute);
        GeneralInfo.add(lbRole);
        GeneralInfo.add(lbStar);

        //GemButtonPanel
        PanelGems.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        PanelGems.add(btGem1);
        PanelGems.add(btGem2);
        PanelGems.add(btGem3);

        // Add Panels to InfoPanel
        InfoPanel.add(GeneralInfo,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        InfoPanel.add(StatTable,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        InfoPanel.add(PanelGems, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(InfoPanel);

    }

    public void ButtonHandler()
    {
        btGem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        btGem2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        btGem3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        cbAttribute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = cbAttribute.getSelectedItem().toString();
                DBAccess db;

                switch(s)
                {
                case "Fire":
                    System.out.println("Fire Selected");
                    fillListModel("Fire");
                    break;
                case "Water":
                    System.out.println("Water Selected");
                    fillListModel("Water");
                    break;
                case "Wood":
                    System.out.println("Wood Selected");
                    fillListModel("Wood");
                    break; 
                case "Light": 
                    System.out.println("Light Selected");
                    fillListModel("Light");
                    break;
                case "Dark":
                    System.out.println("Dark Selected");
                    fillListModel("Dark");
                    break;
                case "_____________________":
                    System.out.println("Bleh");
                    fillListModel("All");           
                    break;
                default:
                    break;


                }

            }
        });

        cbStars.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = cbStars.getSelectedItem().toString();

                switch(s)
                {
                case "One": 
                    System.out.println("One Star");
                    break; 
                case "Two":
                    System.out.println("Two Star");
                    break;
                case "Three":
                    System.out.println("Three Star");
                    break;
                case "Four":
                    System.out.println("Four Star");
                    break;
                case "Five":
                    System.out.println("Five Star");
                    break;
                case "_____________________":
                    System.out.println("Meh");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;      
                }

            }
        });



    }

    protected void fillListModel(String s)
    {
        DBAccess db; 
        ArrayList<Astromon> al = null; 

        try
        {
            dlmAstro.removeAllElements();
            db = new DBAccess(); 
            if(s == "All")
                al =db.getAllAstromons();
            else 
                {
                    al = db.getAstromonByElement(s);
                }

            db.closeDB();


            for(Astromon a: al)
            {
                dlmAstro.addElement(a);

            } 

            aList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        } catch (AstromonException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

-- Database Class

```
package db;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import data.Astromon;
import data.AstromonException;

public class DBAccess {

    Connection con = null;

    public DBAccess() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/monstersuperleague","root","");

    }

    public void closeDB() throws SQLException
    {
        if(con!=null)
            con.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Astromon> getAllAstromons() throws SQLException, AstromonException
    {
        ArrayList<Astromon> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(con!=null)
        {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            String sqlText ="Select * from astromon";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlText);

            while(rs.next())
            {

                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String name = rs.getString(2);
                int role = rs.getInt(3);
                int attribute = rs.getInt(4);
                int hp = rs.getInt(5);
                int atk= rs.getInt(6);
                int def= rs.getInt(7);
                int rec= rs.getInt(8);
                int cr= rs.getInt(9);
                int cd= rs.getInt(10);
                int res= rs.getInt(11);
                int leader= rs.getInt(12);
                int normal= rs.getInt(13);
                int active= rs.getInt(14);
                int gem1= 1;
                int gem2= 1;
                int gem3= 1;
                String icon = rs.getString(18);
                System.out.println("ID: "+id+"Name: "+name+"Role"+role+"Attribut: ");
                Astromon a = new Astromon(id, name, icon, attribute, role, hp, atk, def, rec, cr, cd, res, leader, normal, active, gem1, gem2,gem3);

                aList.add(a);

            }

        }
        return aList;

    }


    public ArrayList<Astromon> getAstromonByElement(String s) throws SQLException, AstromonException
    {

        String element = null; 
        ArrayList<Astromon> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(s == "Fire")
            element="1"; 
        else if(s== "Water")
            element="2";
        else if(s=="Wood")
            element="3";
        else if(s=="Light")
            element="4";
        else if(s=="Dark")
            element="5";
        else 
            getAllAstromons();

        if(con!=null)
        {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sqlText ="Select * from astromon where a_atype="+element;
            ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery(sqlText);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String name = rs.getString(2);
                int role = rs.getInt(3);
                int attribute = rs.getInt(4);
                int hp = rs.getInt(5);
                int atk= rs.getInt(6);
                int def= rs.getInt(7);
                int rec= rs.getInt(8);
                int cr= rs.getInt(9);
                int cd= rs.getInt(10);
                int res= rs.getInt(11);
                int leader= rs.getInt(12);
                int normal= rs.getInt(13);
                int active= rs.getInt(14);
                int gem1= 1;
                int gem2= 1;
                int gem3= 1;
                String icon = rs.getString(18);
                System.out.println("ID: "+id+"Name: "+name+"Role"+role+"Attribut: ");
                Astromon a = new Astromon(id, name, icon, attribute, role, hp, atk, def, rec, cr, cd, res, leader, normal, active, gem1, gem2,gem3);

                aList.add(a);

            }

        }



        return aList;
    }



    public int getCountOfAstromons() throws SQLException
    {
        int count=0; 
        if(con!= null)
        {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            String sqlText = "Select Count(a_id) from astromon";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlText);

            count = rs.getInt(1); 
        } 
        return count;
    }



}
```

I can't find any error in the code. The Informations of the Monsters are written in the Console. But it doesn't get added in the JList. Dx am sitting 3h on it to find the error. Hope you guys can help me out a little bit.

Yeah I know the code is not perfect just a little prototype ^^ I just wanna have that objects are displayed, that I can use the renderer to split the information for better overview of the monster units

Comment: Give MINIMAL code. BTW Your code has many Java errors, the simplest if(s=="Dark") -> s.Equals("Dark")

Comment: okay first time i post a question ^^ and yeah equals also work but i said the code is not perfect :D